# Is there a term for a path in an undirected graph with: (1) the end vertices having degrees $\neq 2$, (2) the other vertices (if any) having degree 2?

Tags: graph-theory

In other words, the path has no "branchings" except possibly at the end vertices.  This question is in the context of analyzing traffic in a network: I am looking at measuring traffic flow and density in each such path.

Comment: So the non-end vertices should have degree 2, not 1 as in the title, correct?

Comment: Correct, thank you.  I also need to correct (1) similarly.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

[Cranston and West](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4434.pdf) define a *thread* (Definition 2.4) to be a trail whose internal vertices all have degree 2, which is similar to what you want (although it doesn't *force* the end vertices to have degree different from 2, and it also potentially allows the endpoints to coincide).

Comment: I see.  I suppose, what I am trying to define would be, of sorts, a *maximal* thread?

Comment: @avs more or less, although I think that definition, as stated, would say that a cycle with at most 1 vertex of degree exceeding 2 is also a maximal thread

Comment: right, I should add "acyclic" to the list of the defining properties.

Answer (score 1):

A path whose end vertices have arbitrary degree and whose interior vertices have degree two is a path that can be obtained via some number of [subdivisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) of an edge. If we start with a graph $G$ whose only vertices of degree two are components consisting of a single vertex and a single loop, then multiple subdivisions of a non-loop edge in $G$ always yields a path whose end vertices have degree not equal to two and whose interior vertices have degree two.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I was looking rather to identify the existing such paths in a given graph than to form them by modifying the graph.

Comment: @avs My guess is there is not a widely accepted name for such subgraphs. If I were you, I would just make up my own name for them, something like strongly embedded arcs or strongly embedded paths (or whatever more descriptive thing you can come up with).